# Unable to connect to SMTP Port no 465

Tags: java, email, smtp, html-email, smtp-auth

I am not able to connect to smtp port no 465, which uses SSL authentication. Earlier it used to work in default port 25, but have changed the setting to point to 465 for outbound emails for all outgoing emails. This works perfectly fine when i use outlook but shows that it cannot connect to port 465.

Below is the error.

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
        javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com, port: 465
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
```

And below is the Javax Mail setting that i use.

```
 Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", 
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.server.username", "test@gamil.com");
    props.put("mail.server.password", "test123");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter",   authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName()); 
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
    session.setDebug(sessionDebug);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log says, `smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com` at port 465 cannot be connected, if you are using gmail, the host should be:`smtp.gmail.com`.

For reference:

**Gmail-**  Host: smtp.gmail.com , Port: 465

**Hotmail-**  Host: smtp.live.com , Port: 587

**Yahoo-**  Host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com , Port: 465

Comment: I am actually trying to tick it but crazy tick is prompting that you can accept an answer after some time

Comment: @Jhanvi I am trying to configure smtp.bizmail, but with every port and Auth combination I get "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)". Can you shed some more light on this error. I am using PHPMailer

Comment: @aarn which port are you using?

Comment: @Jhanvi I have tried using
ssl -> 465
tls ->587
tls -> 25

Comment: @aarn check if these ports are not blocked?

Comment: @Jhanvi if it were blocked, then I would not be able to use it from Outlook as well.