# Java javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, yahoo, yahoo-mail

I create an api to send email via yahoo. On start a get an exception.

My SendMail class:

```
import com.emo.api.MailService;
import com.emo.api.model.MailModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SimpleMail implements MailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Override
    public void sendEmail(final MailModel mailModel) {

        final SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(mailModel.getTo());
        message.setSubject(mailModel.getContent());
        message.setText(mailModel.getContent());

        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
```

My applications.properties:

```
server.port=8082

# Email (MailProperties)
spring.mail.host=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=xyz@yahoo.com
spring.mail.password=ABCD
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.mail.yahoo.com

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000

# TLS , port 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

My Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.emo.rest.mail")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

I use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

On start:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 587
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2211) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.testConnection(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:398) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.mail.MailHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MailHealthIndicator.java:42) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:38) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:75) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:602) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:376) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:214) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

according to this link [Unable to connect to SMTP Port no 465](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566346/unable-to-connect-to-smtp-port-no-465)

i use a port `465` an get this error on start:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.4.jar:1.6.4]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.testConnection(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:398) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.mail.MailHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(MailHealthIndicator.java:42) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:38) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:75) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: *Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message* What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `java 11.0.7`

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I think it can be caused by too frequent health checks
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8213